# Hex file transfer back from pcb

Tags: c, output, lpc

I'm working on a small project using an NXP lpc1769 demo board. I'm using LPCExpresso 5 from CodeRed to program it and I would like to know if I can transfer the application hex/bin file back from the board to the PC. 
Either with the IDE or with any other solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you program the board? With JTAG, ISP or some bootloader solution?

Comment: Not sure if the same, but at least LPC-Link 2 seems to support using J-Link firmware for debugging. It *should* allow viewing flash memory contents. I don't know if LPCExpressor supports that or if you can download J-link PC software from Segger (might require J-Link serial number)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to ISP pin and UART0 lines, you can use [FlashMagic](http://www.flashmagictool.com/%E2%80%8E) to display memory one sector at the time.